# Two different styles in a single textview with different gravity and height

Tags: android, textview, android-styles

I am looking for a textview which looks like [image]. I have used below code for the implementation of this..

```
SpannableString text;
    text = new SpannableString(bal_dollars.getText());
    int index = bal_dollars.getText().toString().indexOf(".");
    text.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getApplicationContext(),
            R.style.HeroGraphicBalanceSmallFont), index, bal_dollars
            .getText().toString().length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    bal_dollars.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

here is the style used in the span..

```
<style name="HeroGraphicBalanceSmallFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">top|right</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top|right</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/status_text</item>
    <item name="customFont">fonts/HeroicCondensedMedium.ttf</item>
</style>
```

everything looks fine except the spacing of targeted span of text i.e decimal part gravity.. [image]. I tried all the xml attributes. Please help

Comment: I would look into the `baselineShift` attribute of `TextPaint`.

Comment: thanks @kcoppock, i have dug more into extending `MetricAffectingSpan` class and changing the `baselineshift` attribute. It worked like a charm :)

Comment: 1.5 years too late.. but doesn't [SuperscriptSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.html) work for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I cracked it. I am posting this as it might be helpful for others and thanks to @kcoppock for the hint.
I have extended `MetricAffectingSpan` class which affects character-level text formatting in a way that changes the width or height of characters extend this class.

```
public class CustomCharacterSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
double ratio = 0.5;

public CustomCharacterSpan() {
}

public CustomCharacterSpan(double ratio) {
    this.ratio = ratio;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint paint) {
    paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
}}
```

use this to update the text in your views..

```
String string = tv.getText().toString();
    SpannableString text = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
    int index = tv.getText().toString().indexOf(".");
    text.setSpan(new CustomCharacterSpan(), index, string.length(),
            SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//u can use ur own ratio using another constructor
    tv.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```