# Align top two textviews with different font sizes

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Im using constraint layout and i want to achieve the following:

[image]

The app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf attribute bottom aligns the two textviews, is there any way to top align the two? The regular app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf is not working of course because of the size differences.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: is it helpful? http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/09/set-styling-text-on-textview.html

Comment: There is no code, its just two text views with attributes inside constraint layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center align two textviews in a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931078/horizontally-center-align-two-textviews-in-a-layout)

Comment: Not the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems there is no a convenient way of doing this and a custom view must be implemented. I've taken inspiration from here:

https://github.com/fabiomsr/MoneyTextView

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_unit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:text="$"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="120"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_unit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Like this .

[image]

Comment: that is more easy..great +1

Comment: It's easy .And `ConstraintLayout` is similar to `RelativeLayout` .

Comment: Its not a proper solution, you've just used a hardcoded margin to align both views.

Comment: What do you want to do for it ?

Answer (score 0):

try this
you can use **[Html.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)** for this purpose

> **Html.fromHtml**
>   Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string.

```
yourTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<sup><small>$</small></sup>42"));
```

or try this use **SpannableString**

```
TextView textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("$42");
sb.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(sb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Not getting the desired effect

Comment: No, the two texts are not exactly aligned. The dollar sign is higher than the number.

Comment: @EvgeniRoitburg use **SpannableString**

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
String s = "$<sub>12 </sub>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s)); // 12 will cropped 
// solution:
        s = "$<sub>12 </sub>\t  "; // add behind ending of sup tag the tabulator \t,
// but not char \t but only press to TAB key!!! in source code
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s)); // 12 is visible correctly
```

http://android.okhelp.cz/whittled-superscript-sup-tag-textview-android-issue/